# Unix find with GNU Make to auto-update files

Tags: makefile, find, haml, unix

I have `.haml` files and want to convert them automatically into `.html` files and update the latter when `.haml` is changed.

The generic makefile rule is no problem:

```
%.html: %.haml
    hamlpy $< $@
```

But now I need a rule or a command to do the following:

- find all `X.haml` files in `templates/`
- execute `make X.html` command, where X is the same filename (`haml` is replaced with `html`).

I can't find how to do this with GNU Make or Unix find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all of your `*.haml` files are well name (i.e. no spaces or other funny characters), you can do it with a call to `find(1)`:

```make
HAML_FILES = $(shell find templates/ -type f -name '*.haml')
HTML_FILES = $(HAML_FILES:.haml=.html)

all: $(HTML_FILES)

%.html : %.haml
        hamlpy $< $@
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use GNU make `wildcard` function to find files in a certain directory:

```
INDIR := templates
OUTDIR := ${CURDIR}

haml_files := $(wildcard ${INDIR}/*.haml)
html_files := $(subst ${INDIR}/,${OUTDIR}/,${haml_files:.haml=.html})

all : ${html_files}

clean :
    rm -f ${html_files}

${OUTDIR}/%.html : ${INDIR}/%.haml
    hamlpy $< $@

.PHONY : all clean
```

`INDIR` and `OUTDIR` can be customized on the command line, for example, to use the current directory for inputs and iutputs:

```
$ make INDIR=. OUTDIR=.
```

Comment: What if they can be deeper than `templates`?

Comment: The above assumes that `.haml` files are all in one folder no matter how deep, e.g.  `templates/a/b/c/d/e/`.